# How to detect multiple gestures in android?

Tags: android, gesture, detection

I want to detect multiple gestures, for example, detect the scroll with THREE fingers.
When I do a scroll with three fingers, set text for a textview into "YES", for other cases, set it into "NO".

This is what I got so far:

```
private GestureDetector detector;

detector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), this);

layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The problem is: in the method `onTouch`, we can detect how many fingers are `touching(event.getpointcount())`, but i cant get which action such as scroll.
if I write like this in this method: `return detector.onTouchEvent(event)`
and I write some methods such as `onDown`, `onFling` etc, I could detect down, scroll, fling etc but this is just for only one finger.

I hope u got what I mean. I mix up the two things:

- `multi touch` We can know how many fingers but we dont know which action
- `single gesture` We know which action is being done but we dont know how many fingers we use.

What I want is combine them: gestures with multi fingers, such as scroll with three fingers etc.

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be try `event.getPointerCount();`

Comment: event.getPointerCount() is used in the method OnTouch where we can just detect ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP, ACTION_MOVE. we cant detect ACTION_SCROLL there